# Maximum time limit of setTimeout in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, settimeout, v8

I have registered some `setTimeout` functions in node like below.

```
//Formula: minutes * 60 > seconds * 1000 > miliseconds.
setTimeout(() => {console.log("One minute")}, 1 * 60 * 1000)        //delay 60000
setTimeout(() => {console.log("Five minutes")}, 5 * 60 * 1000)      //delay 300000
setTimeout(() => {console.log("Ten minutes")}, 10 * 60 * 1000)      //delay 600000
setTimeout(() => {console.log("Thirty minutes")}, 30 * 60 * 1000)   //delay 1800000
setTimeout(() => {console.log("One hour")}, 60 * 60 * 1000)         //delay 3600000
setTimeout(() => {console.log("Two hours")}, 120 * 60 * 1000)       //delay 7200000
setTimeout(() => {console.log("Five hours")}, 300 * 60 * 1000)      //delay 18000000
```

Now the issue is `setTimeout` that take more than **10 minutes** is not working when I read `setTimeout` documentation it's support **24.8 days**.

> When delay is larger than 2147483647 or less than 1, the delay will be set to 1

[image]

All delay's value is less than 2147483647 than why it is not working ???

Comment: after 10 mins of setTimeout , you are not getting the console.log is that your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got answer when I created issue on `node.js` repo, basically it's not node.js but heroku issue. 
In heroku **free** dynos are unique because they go to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity so more than 30 minutes of time is not working
 [Github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22860)

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure what you exactly want to achieve here. If you want to execute something at later stage use [Cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) instead of `setTimeout`.

And answer to your original question is

`JavaScript store the delay as a 32-bit signed Integer internally. This causes an Integer overflow when using delays larger than 2147483647, resulting in the timeout being executed immediately.`

Above code is working fine.

[image]

Comment: All delay's value is less than 2147483647 as mention in question so didn't overflow, this is not a solution to use cron instead of setTimeout.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. And your code works fine by the way, I tired running it. I don't see any issue in it.