# Why setTimeout is not working for 2 hours time set in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, settimeout

I am trying to execute some code under **setTimeout** which is set to be at 2 hours.
Means after 2 hours on end point hit I want to performing the following operations:

1. Delete Editable document on basis of an ID.
2. Pushing the tasks in one of the Collection
3. Setting some variable

All this needs to be executed after 2 hours.
So before that I tried to execute it after 2 minutes so I put the time 120000. And it executed it successfully. But when I put the 2 hours time which is: 7200000 it doesn't execute. I Logged out and logged in after 2-3 hours again but the all remains same. No tasks get performed.

All this is on production server means on heroku side and as well as localhost. Doesn't matter.
What I am doing wrong?

```
setTimeout(function () {
                                Editable.deleteMany({userId: editableData.userId}, function (err) {
                                  if (err) {
                                    res.render('error', {error: err});
                                  }
                                  else {
                                    console.log("User.updateOne({Addtasks.id"+ element._id +"})");
                                    User.updateMany({"Addtasks._id":element._id},
                                    {$set: {"Addtasks.$.displayDelete" :'none', "Addtasks.$.displayLock" :'inline'}},
                                    function (error, success) {
                                      if(error)
                                      {
                                        res.render('error', {error: err});
                                      }
                                      else {
                                        User.findOne({"Addtasks._id": element._id}, function (err, dataAfter) {
                                          if (dataAfter){
                                            console.log("===========================This is before pushing the data to Admin Dashboard=======================================")
                                            // console.log("element = "+ element + " and tasks = " + tasks);
                                            dataAfter.Addtasks.forEach(eleID => {
                                              if(element.id == eleID.id)
                                              {
                                                console.log("eleID = "+ eleID);
                                                User.findOneAndUpdate({tag:"Admin"}, {$push: {Addtasks: eleID}},
                                                function (error, AdminData) {
                                                  if (error) {
                                                    res.render('error', {error: err});
                                                  }  else {
                                                    console.log("Added the tasks to the admin's dashboard");
                                                  }
                                                });
                                              }
                                            });

                                          }
                                        });
                                        console.log("success");
                                        console.log("Deleted and Updated the display Button none successfully after 30 seconds!");
                                      }
                                    });
                                  }
                                });
                             

 }, 720*1000);
```

Comment: Same problem is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294430/maximum-time-limit-of-settimeout-in-node-js

Comment: @Aracturat
There its written: In heroku free dynos are unique because they go to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity so more than 30 minutes of time is not working

So does that mean cron would work like that as well if I want to use the cron instead of setTimeOut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the free dynos automatically put to sleep after 30 minutes, therefore, it's probably not getting executed as the server is not live during your waiting time:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22860

Also, it is better to use Cron Jobs for such tasks, and not setTimeOut:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

you can set it up like this:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('0 0 0/2 1/1 * ? *', function() {
  \\ YOUR CODE HERE
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
job.start();
```

If you don't know how to write Cron expressions, you have websites that can help you with that, such as:
http://www.cronmaker.com/

NOTE: Cron Jobs, much like setTimeout is only good as long as your server is live, so that still not resolve your problem. as for solutions:

**Workarounds**

1. External Add-on: using [addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/newrelic) such as [Relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/synthetics/synthetic-monitoring/getting-started/types-synthetic-monitors#) that will access your app's URL to prevent it from sleeping
2. Heroku Add-on: using Heroku Scheduler add supported features for recurring tasks, you can choose between [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#scheduling-jobs) or [Heroku Clock Process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes) depends on what type of job you are trying to run

Comment: So Cron Jobs would not require the need of the server if its on sleep or not then?

Comment: unfortunately, no... it stops the execution of your program using syscall, there are some workarounds, I'll adedit d my response to provide some alternatives you should check out

Comment: No. I mean I am asking that cron jobs would work fine after 2 hours or days or months as well?

Comment: Cron Job, much like SetTimeout will not work if your dyno is put to sleep. I edited my response with additional details.
And Cron job is good for days, weeks, months... what ever you want, as long as the server is active

Comment: @Biku7 hi, if that solved your problem, please mark this answer as the correct answer

Comment: How to use heroku scheduler? Do I need to change the whole scheedule and cron job code? I am using node-schedule npm module currently to schedule the tasks.

Comment: Please refer this qstn of mine:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330834/how-to-schedule-the-task-on-event-click-change-with-heroku-scheduler-in-nodejs